# To delete only files that has at least one digit in its file name not directories

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I know how to delete only files not directories as follows:

```
find /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -iv {} \;
```

I learned the above snippet from [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84317/how-to-delete-files-only-but-keep-the-directory-structure)

If i want to delete files that has at least one digit in its file name.

```
find /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -iv *[0-9]* {} \;
```

Should this work for my case? Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome on the StackOverflow! Note, your question is not really about programming, it is more like about Linux. I suggest to re-post your question on the https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a glob pattern in `-name` option and then use `-delete` option:

```
find /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*[0-9]*' -delete
```

If `-delete` is not available then:

```
find /path/to/directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*[0-9]*' -exec rm -iv {} \;
```